# su: Authentication failure on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication

When I try to switch to another user from the command line using "su", I get an authentication failure, as shown below:

> su - otheruser
>
> Password: *****
>
> su: Authentication failure

Yet I know that the password is correct because I can successfully log in to the desk top as the other user from the Ubuntu login screen.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

See this page for what you should use for a rootshell: [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

This page *also* will explain how to get a terminal as another user.
Short version: `sudo -i -u <username>`

There's an Ubuntu SO-based site here: https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to be root to do "su".  You can "sudo su - user" or you can "sudo su -" then do "su - user".
Enter the password of the user you are now when you do the sudo.  ex. "whoami"

Comment: Don't use su on Ubuntu.

Comment: My question is why is it there if I should not use it?  Ok, how about this one: "sudo -u <username> <command>" ?

Comment: Please see my answer for why - the official justification is listed there.

Comment: sudo -i is proper if you need a rootshell. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6188826&postcount=4